# How to add steps dynamically in a job using spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am using spring batch where-in I have a use case to configure job with dynamic steps. The number of steps will depend based on the request sent by user.
Currently I am using the tasklet methodology to process the step.

I do not want to process the data in chunks.

any way to workaround this, so i can configure job with dynamic steps.

please find the code snippet from JobConfiguration.

```
@Bean
public Job createBatchJob() {
    return jobFactory.get(JOB_TYPE)
            .preventRestart()
            .start(step1())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step step1() {
    return stepFactory.get(STEP_TYPE)
    .tasklet(batchTasklet).build();
}
```

How can I configure dynamic steps in above configuration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create dynamic steps in Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853908/how-to-create-dynamic-steps-in-spring-batch)

Comment: this is a different case and not an exact duplicate of How to create dynamic steps in Spring Batch. basically we need dynamic steps but to be added lazily to a job , after the job is built.

so say i have configured a job, to process some bunch of files. but the user requests a batch and could submit multiple files, now based on no of files user has submitted via an Rest api, i want to add those many number of steps to job created.

is this case supported of adding steps to job after its built? or is there a way to create job configuration dynamically.
hope this clarifies the question.?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the job definition is dynamic and depends on request parameters. So that's is a Spring question rather than a Spring Batch question, you are trying to create beans dynamically (the job/steps beans). You would probably need to inject the bean registry in your controller and update the job/step beans at runtime (See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051394/how-to-add-bean-instance-at-runtime-in-spring-webapplicationcontext).

Comment: Conceptually, our job configuration is only one, but it has multiple steps for each execution. Can we use chunk processing for this?  A custom itemReader with chunk size as 1. Can each chunk be processed in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

this is a different case and not an exact duplicate of [How to create dynamic steps in Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853908/how-to-create-dynamic-steps-in-spring-batch).

basically we need dynamic steps but to be added lazily to a job , after the job is built.

so say i have configured a job, to process some bunch of files.
but the user requests a batch and could submit multiple files, now based on no of files user has submitted via an Rest api, i want to add those many number of steps to job created.

is this case supported of adding steps to job after its built?

or is there a way to create job configuration dynamically.

hope this clarifies the question.

Comment: reason to do this is we want to track processing of each file seperately and report the status , so step is a natural choice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

> SimpleJobBuilder

```
 // Start your dynamic batch job building with first request sent by the user. 
 SimpleJobBuilder jobBuilder = jobBuilderFactory.get(YOUR_JOB_NAME)
                           .start(new TaskletStep(YOUR_TASKLET_STEP));
```

You can write your own generic **GenericTaskletStep** class which takes the user inputs for batch processing. Embed you batch processing logic in that generic class. Then iterate over the inputs and add **GenericTaskletStep** dynamically.

```
// Skip the first input that already added in start step above.
for(int i = 1; i < inputs.size(); i++) {
    jobBuilder.next(new GenericTaskletStep(TASKLET_STEP_NAME))
}

// Finally build your job
jobBuilder.build();
```